# Generic Factory using Enum that populates fields

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I can't figure out how to have this factory `createLetterMap` produce default values for its instance...

' How to loop over enums ' is not really the question as I understand it to be impossible because types aren't available at run-time, but maybe I'm missing something about string emums?

```
enum Letter{
    A = "A",
    B = "B",
    E = "E",
    I = "I",

}
type Vowl = Letter.A | Letter.E | Letter.I

class LMAP{
    test(){}
}
function createLetterMap<T extends Letter>(){
    let lmapExtended = new LMAP() as LMAP & {
        [key in T]?:string
    };

    // ?? create default values for keys somehow ??

    return lmapExtended;
}

let vowlMap = createLetterMap<Vowl>()

vowlMap[Letter.E] = "Eat" // OK
// vowlMap[Letter.B] = "Bat" // Error! Good!

let defaultVal = vowlMap[Letter.A]; // undefined. Would like it to be populated.
```

More generally, I'd like to use unions of string enums to produce keyed objects where I can use the enums as keys for situations kinda like this:

```
fn(v:Vowl){

  ...

  letterMap[v].someVowlReleatedWork()

  ...

}
```

I've explored alternatives just using an actual Map that ~work~, but it seems like there's a way to make things cleaner if I can just specify the types correctly...

The best I've come up with requires making an additional array of the enums included in the union type and using BOTH the union and the array for the factory; something like below, which seems kind of dumb:

```
...

let Vowls = [Letter.A,... ]
createLetterMap<Vowl>(Vowls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use type definitions as a values since they are removed at runtime - `for(let key of keyof Vowl` wouldn't work.

You could implement the map as a class or if you really want to extract keys at runtime you can use a custom transformer such as [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys).

```js
enum Letter {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  E = "E",
  I = "I",

}
type Vowl = Letter.A | Letter.E | Letter.I

interface IMapper<T> { operation(value: T): void }

class VowlMapper implements IMapper<Vowl> {
  operation(vowel: Vowl) {
    console.log("VowlMapper: " + vowel);
  }
}

class LetterMap<T extends Letter> {

  private map: IMapper<T> & { [key in T]?: string };

  constructor(map: IMapper<T>) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  get(letter: T) {
    return this.map[letter] ?? letter;
  }

  set(letter: T, value: any) {
    this.map[letter] = value;
  }

  operation(value: T) {
    return this.map.operation(value);
  }

}

let vowlMap = new LetterMap(new VowlMapper())

vowlMap.set(Letter.E, "Eat");
// vowlMap.set(Letter.B, "Bat"); // Error! Good!

console.log(vowlMap.get(Letter.A))  // A
//console.log(vowlMap.get(Letter.B))  // error
console.log(vowlMap.get(Letter.E))  // Eat

vowlMap.operation(Letter.A); // VowlMapper: A
```

Check out the [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAMiALokAnGBvYMYEEYC8MARLsQDTYwBChJ1FVAoncU4zgJKuePAC+wRAE8ADiBgA1APYB3ADZ0EyNADp8AH3hIUqVSy3LdqzsGABLMLoBmAQwDGEzgFlbo8agA8AFQB8mGGkPW0RzaTAACgA3W3kIEAAuGG8ASiSo6XMAExhBYHt5WwBnIqk5eVd3NBhzKFF5EChwRFKXNw9PGQV-LBwgtBCwyIzZEHkkrvkUzCoce3Ci6QbVeWkAcwjiScqPJOIYAGoYEbGUgG4qQTyC4tKjNEqfGBAADxQwLLudNB6zHFFUOYYigYFA3Ek2lUvH4YAAyAIAbQA1iBhDUwMkALoAfiSRUQgLAa1yFyo8zA+NQEHsiGkqAiYNEEJ2aB8vmmvRwMEQAAtzEVVIy6IyLjg8jg1kgIg0VKgkqkZlyYKgkBBUBjefzBW4ETLdJiYNjsTA9WhRbk-jAilLTXLkuRjrF4klbGBhBzZty+QLGbrvqgDUQYnEQObxYFgqFwtEnYlkh6lSrEGqNd7taJVP1UINo8H4udLmY8jLjuVKnQwCBZNpZZUIpXq9t2mgIikUmYRhU3KprYgIvc9EwHWwQsQCwB6celhSVHtSgeqajD6ij84wScwJioVB0gCEMAA4tJpFld2ZyYtlqsNp3Z5K+wvcG2cBvcMBJxeliAVutomXu-e-b+ouz7rlOaA7qg+QLF+P43v+GaAQuTCgRuTAhB2CGZpGQxAbK6gFkAA).

Comment: Yea, just hiding the actual map is probably the better, or at least safer way to go...

There's something bothering me though about the fact I couldn't find a way to state that "instance A has keys K [B,C,D]" and be off and writing A[B] without having to create multiple levels of indirection and composition... 

Thanks for the approach though!

Answer (score 0):

A ""clean-ish"" approach I've found (at least when it comes to using the output) uses a const array of enums. The solution is a little... thick; and I think there's some serious risk of overwriting LMAP fields with the input enum collection...

Though when assigning defaults values, it seems I need to cast to any, but I'm not sure why. Given that the input array *must* be a set of Letter enums, I'm not *worried* about the cast per say, but it is a little weird...

```
enum Letter{
    A = "A",
    B = "B",
    E = "E",
    I = "I"    
}

// By using a const array for subsets we can have an iterable structure and something to derive type from
const Vowls = <const> [
    Letter.A,
    Letter.E,
    Letter.I
];

// Whatever class we'll 'extend'
class LMAP{};
// Accepts a const array of the original enum type, uses it for type info and iteration 
function createLMAP<T extends Readonly<Array<Letter>>,T2>(letterArray:T,defaultVal:T2){    
    let n = new LMAP() as LMAP & {[key in typeof letterArray[number]]:T2};
    letterArray.forEach(key=>{                
        n[key as T[number]] = defaultVal as any; // Not sure why the need to cast to any here...
    });
    return n;
}

// voila
let vm = createLMAP(Vowls,0);

// tests
Vowls.forEach(v=>{
    vm[v] += 1;
})
vm[Letter.A] = 1;
vm[Letter.B] = 1; // Error thanks to no implicit any

// derive a union type for use elsewhere...
type Vowl = typeof Vowls[number]; 
// e.g.
function work(v:Vowl){
    vm[v] = 1;
}
work(Letter.A)
work(Letter.B) // Err !
```

I'm not accepting this as the answer, but I am going this route personally.